# Typescript: How to type guard array value between primitive and non primitive array

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write uniqueBy function where we get only unique results. I planned to have single API call with the name `uniqueBy` for all the variations. So I went with function overloads concept.

We can get both Primitive and Non-primitive array as input. When I try to access the Non-primitive array after type guarding it I am getting the below error
`cannot be used to index type 'T'`.

```js
/**
 * When I write a separate function as shown at the bottom of the file, it is working fine. When I try to use function overlloads, it is not working as shown below.
 */
function uniqueBy<T extends Primitive>(arrayList: T[]): T[]; // primitive overlload
function uniqueBy<T extends AnyObject, K extends keyof T>(
  arrayList: T[],
  objectKeyToCompareWith: K
): T[];// non-primitive array along with object key as input overlload
function uniqueBy<T extends AnyObject>(
  arrayList: T[],
  iterateeFunction: UniqueIterateeMapFunction<T>
): T[];// non-primitive array with iterateeFunction as input overlload
function uniqueBy<T extends AnyObject | Primitive, K extends keyof T>( // implementation signature
  arrayList: T[],
  objectKeyOrIterateeFunction?: K | UniqueIterateeMapFunction<T>
): T[] {
  if (isPrimitive(arrayList)) {
    const uniquePrimitiveArray: T[] = [...new Set(arrayList)];
    return uniquePrimitiveArray;
  }
  if (isArrayOfObjects(objectKeyOrIterateeFunction) && isObjectKey(objectKeyOrIterateeFunction)) { // type guard to check if it is array of objects but not primitive array and it is object key
    const objectKeyToCompareWith = objectKeyOrIterateeFunction ;
    const uniqueRecordsWithPredicateFunction: T[] = arrayList.reduce(
      (accumulateUniqueRecords: T[], item: T): T[] => {
        const valueOfObjectKeyPassedInItemBeingProcessed =
         // Error: When accessing the non-primitive array with the key 
        //Type '((K | UniqueIterateeMapFunction<T> | undefined) & object[]) & ((number | keyof K | keyof object[]) & (number | keyof object[]))' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
          item[objectKeyToCompareWith];
        const foundUniqueRecord: boolean = !accumulateUniqueRecords.some(
          (accumulatedUniqueRecord: T): boolean => {
            const {
              [objectKeyToCompareWith]: objectKeyValueInAccumulatedRecord,
            } = accumulatedUniqueRecord;
            const isValueOfTheObjectKeyPassedIsEqual: boolean =
              valueOfObjectKeyPassedInItemBeingProcessed ===
              objectKeyValueInAccumulatedRecord;
            return isValueOfTheObjectKeyPassedIsEqual;
          }
        );
        if (foundUniqueRecord) {
          const appendUniqueItemToArray: T[] = appendNewItemToArray(
            accumulateUniqueRecords,
            item
          );
          return appendUniqueItemToArray;
        }
        return accumulateUniqueRecords;
      },
      [] 
    );
    return uniqueRecordsWithPredicateFunction;
  }
  
  if (isFunction(objectKeyOrIterateeFunction)) {
    const uniqueRecordsWithIterateeMapFunction: T[] = arrayList.reduce(
      (accumulateUniqueRecords: T[], item: T): T[] => {
        const valueOfItemBeingProcessedFromIterateeFunction = objectKeyOrIterateeFunction(
          item
        );
        const foundUniqueRecord: boolean = !accumulateUniqueRecords.some(
          (accumulatedUniqueRecord: T): boolean => {
            const isIterateeFunctionOutputEqual: boolean =
              valueOfItemBeingProcessedFromIterateeFunction ===
              objectKeyOrIterateeFunction(accumulatedUniqueRecord);
            return isIterateeFunctionOutputEqual;
          }
        );
        if (foundUniqueRecord) {
          const appendUniqueItemToArray: T[] = appendNewItemToArray(
            accumulateUniqueRecords,
            item
          );
          return appendUniqueItemToArray;
        }
        return accumulateUniqueRecords;
      },
      []
    );
    return uniqueRecordsWithIterateeMapFunction;
  }

  return arrayList;
}

export type Primitive =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | bigint
  | symbol
  | undefined
  | null;
export type AnyObject = Record<ObjectKey, any>;
export type ObjectKey = string | number | symbol;
interface UniqueIterateeMapFunction<T> {
  (arg1: T): unknown;
}
function isPrimitive<T>(value: T | Primitive): value is Primitive {
  return value == null || /^[sbn]/.test(typeof value);
}
function isObject(value: unknown): value is object {
  const valueType:
    | "undefined"
    | "object"
    | "boolean"
    | "number"
    | "string"
    | "function"
    | "symbol"
    | "bigint" = typeof value;
  return value != null && (valueType == "object" || valueType == "function");
}
function isString<T>(value: string | T): value is string {
  return typeof value === "string";
}
function isNumber<T>(value: number | T): value is number {
  return typeof value === "number";
}
function isSymbol<T>(value: symbol | T): value is symbol {
  return typeof value === "symbol";
}
function isObjectKey<T>(value: T | ObjectKey): value is keyof T {
  if (isObject(value)) {
    return isString(value) || isNumber(value) || isSymbol(value);
  }
  return false;
}
function isArray<T = any>(value: any): value is T[] {
  return (
    Boolean(value) &&
    (Boolean(Array.isArray)
      ? Array.isArray(value)
      : value.toString() === "[object Array]")
  );
}
function isFunction<T>(value: T | Function): value is Function {
  return value instanceof Function;
}
const appendNewItemToArray = <T,>(arrayList: T[], item: T): T[] => {
  const newArrayWithAppendedItem: T[] = [...arrayList, item];
  return newArrayWithAppendedItem;
};
export function isNonPrimitive(x: unknown): x is object {
    return !isPrimitive(x);
}
function isArrayOfObjects(value: unknown): value is object[] {
    return isArray(value) && value.every(isNonPrimitive);
}

/**
 * When I write a separate function like below it is working fine.
 */
function uniqueWithKey<T extends AnyObject, K extends keyof T>(
  arrayList: T[],
  objectKeyToCompareWith: K
): T[] {
  const uniqueRecordsWithPredicateFunction: T[] = arrayList.reduce(
    (accumulateUniqueRecords: T[], item: T): T[] => {
      const valueOfObjectKeyPassedInItemBeingProcessed: T[K] =
        item[objectKeyToCompareWith];
      const foundUniqueRecord: boolean = !accumulateUniqueRecords.some(
        (accumulatedUniqueRecord: T): boolean => {
          const {
            [objectKeyToCompareWith]: objectKeyValueInAccumulatedRecord,
          } = accumulatedUniqueRecord;
          const isValueOfTheObjectKeyPassedIsEqual: boolean =
            valueOfObjectKeyPassedInItemBeingProcessed ===
            objectKeyValueInAccumulatedRecord;
          return isValueOfTheObjectKeyPassedIsEqual;
        }
      );
      if (foundUniqueRecord) {
        const appendUniqueItemToArray: T[] = appendNewItemToArray(
          accumulateUniqueRecords,
          item
        );
        return appendUniqueItemToArray;
      }
      return accumulateUniqueRecords;
    },
    []
  );
  return uniqueRecordsWithPredicateFunction;
}
```

As there is a good amount of code, kept the code in typescript playground. I have written good comments to make the code readable.
[Playground link on issue I am facing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUh1ALApgO0gSUgdwE4EsAuikAhpAM6IAOx2xhkAZgK7IDG+uA9qsWefJ0w98kfEkgAjTvnycAtpE4NR4hrgA2iADSQCuvpk7YA1rmQBzRmcQA6OElQZ82AJ6jOkJhUYt2XVJwAbojY6uqcxAAmZDp6uHzI0lhGphYkfGQCQpKI4Zg2UCDA4MxsHNyeyLgAjkyIAEIuADwAKpCIAB6EyNGQAAp4cgS4wQB8ABQ0tC4AMvH4AFyQLQDaALoAlEurawDckMDAkJSDw8GKwaHhUSW+5agsNXWNre1dKL0AgsguAPISACtEOwdABpN7dXrGRAuJTLCZQEjYaZzMiLZbrLSIziA4H4UEwlqcADC8mo2EQsAI8CWoPAWwxe0OkESyAAtCdcEMOOcpsQ3MRwmlMNTFLj2JBoQK+GZKEwREEQmEIpFbmV-JUng1mm1OpC+N8-uL8AjIEiUfNtpjEQQQnREIgAGJ3fxLACqVVqiDQhFohEQAFliJRneruK1RvSrUyjqyOaceUQ+W4RWJdL77U6XRVeLpkHKFZdlTdSn4Ko8vS9de8egafv8gRKAD79BMjbSQcF6j58KVwloTA5HLmUTRyFD4Ogasi4czIOhMCmI5Oo9E7LFmnGN-Ew37YH12-2hsvIAD8tMgLY9WoPfodQZD2eQEajjMgAG8bcpxvEBlyzogkzIvyq4bBsH6ImarDcGimpen+3Ltp8wEuNGkAALyQCsNg4cgiCYJAADKiD4EBFpohseyQZAFL4IuDyenUCEAch0y7IiAC+X6QD+ZCsfyvwMA2eJkOMW54gSfz7hmR5PuBABk8n6MJ7CSWJxqSXut6Zse9xgR+Q6iC4lBEOYTA0JE7iQKwSCsMYujKHEfDJooyjiewfASPKLJJJyiG8ihJA9Om+hitukowtR0HILB7k7i4RKknI5KUqKmFxZp0mHg6ukauxZpQTBIgVnUABKwJGNEVJiAMiCRLgrD2rl3BoZhK7zDYFKREwrCAdRZqTKwrBMHITDqPa15euV0HYNE0axIQcjbAyOwYaMEEFZt1lFZAgSCnUgkqfFfS8BQkRoMgB5yPUiBmOYAycL1ZBnRh-WbcyACiyJGEsCAoCQQ2IM9d0qEQcZ+QB5r8lgopiEQUqQG9ZqHC0xlEAA5OM4zglejHejJ97Bs1z4DpelSRIgah4ZEClhXi6y01jyAjRIIRk32yg4xFsJucaDOQEp4zM3IrPYOzMJwnFDMbOj1nEMgiQiKzngvbIeYUx0RkmZA6MtOjBRbVttpyCsGWEiSZI0KlYhUYbhUxSIDCcCwkSTWVFWzUsUicJo8sYZAACExBDSNY0TXj02VWQNhkPIfV2wVg3DaN42EK7Ece5Ey1e5wPuIH76HrZ+CebdFsHFyXm2mxp5tJSl1XwGsSxmy4ABq+3esgnwhyn9qRJHs0bpXkAcf7wfJ2Hadu4gA+RPlw9lyI8Tt+oB0MC0SBHZJJ3PXVaBkB9tSCjnecF0jdt7aviCHTXLg72dF1XTdd0PU9L3oR-5+Gy3K91Bd3cT1TnVWe89K60XovoX+1916b1vvfPeB8j7qFAXbLiCcNgoM2rgb8TsXbT1nuBCuCdF4kEoCZHo08rpEn4qhN8bUyEfAAHL4SoZwGh4wv4FXHqHIB+DM4xE4WaY2nCMGcPAdgHgDCKF41YTQzBBU0F23ETwHuk9EB8JmtEeRHEh5VzWIjTaojNrKLgu7TRZAG61Xqo1QgxN56KO4rxYm6ltyZW0rJMMyB9JEO2g7UxM9+EN3cYTR8njWpQ1mB1LqPV45bSTjw8OWpZ5kHmumRAS1lgrXWGtDadsSGXzXk-W6FhX5AzOo6bA8hglZk8f7FuWkCY1JPBwyuwj0HyPtrBXB0ikmZxPr7VAmEg6qN4RncxMc44tJLvE3uU8xmVWzpIXOAyck+OITteI1Tia-HlAWQ+5l1D9PzoMwRBUCnQKKS-Spb86oVKqY04mGFP7DwKvUrKd4mn3BmWo9OvTNFGOHiYzZDynw7PwHspBHSFHnwBYbbBPFum-KmpnQhnCSHBnIUiv+i1qEoXCRiphLCcVsJQlMyu3DZnqPmbNARLy2kl1hUokiECCU9K9LIlCULFGGxMRStRGio7aN0QVdY1FGUmJKgE8xQTGkPjsZxcAiJeUoVXOxLi4BOiUCMCIfAaNWz-kTK9M0LY0R4AsIiFswtRYWqWafZANqJCzjMPgG1ZAXAix9jal2lNrCqmNSyMayCNUdC1dgHVerDRHX9rPJoW8YQ6Hli4UY7FNXaq1kQONbhMKmpBpalmbMTXuqkEG51IQGDByIJQ2VRMnwRlyUBcwABGRZLBjCJCEGqtUJ59DMUTBGcY5zthk17e2Bk5zQojvOBXEx46P4BrCJeFswAAB6KwyASGQGsYANhCBonGLqkycJzmiK4qWe4yljQDo7ksVt7avFLHHfEOmEoK75I7qjEyCxqItgAETeqpnVH937IA-rikBzav7vYDPAwVX9VqQgwf9T+nNFhENkx-We-waHf1uo9eobDIHHXmGdT+-2B7EBHo7vPGdHdA6YWZguxSPFzkfqIHO0DxpSNNhbCxvV7HMPcB-Sert574iEWcHdftg7yASbSC2FoY7aNPpQ5YadzKJHpso1fJ5mFkOyfMD+ztAnUDxEYfm7AUnr0BpFgWzJD6lMJHM7kkx5GtN1B0yB+D2BDPgFPU+fQhEi0+0s1fJYuHi1kwU-Z7TymgvqGc+p1ArnlCzvY+Fn2Pm-O1PiJmkLdQh0tkzYpmLvYJbKDaBXeFvEjpXqvt46iQKyDibNeYWrdRwLcf0GZmz2A2uIA6y2MTcW+sAsUSY8t6gKBGf8-EGhrw2o-AmNJxNxX3NPtWmpuiGmyWQHqMs45I2BbyWouMPbdrxg0JsLNlCGw3qnkgJd670wRtvWi3UHdnBmt3XGOBD+unq7hRoWsITiJhPGf0MTPLiACuQGJqtogT7HmbYgY+h28tepwnlVxdFUjIjMMwBy6Y-tWhaAmO1NEqTjaLNWoXXJJC8KYBoQ3T4uO96LXCdhHC5P8ALXSbbGiiWWT4SZ9SFnmK2fpLVSmkNabweme4JOwCHQb3IDbYIe9kBNZPrirks0JiA6-jbMEcYHQwczb4ihG+25RLSdver+HoUpb6J8Y19hx6ju7Q7jYRAlwXC8UYQro3-XO3gFABAaA9h-oYBwLaEg5AqA0HtD4Wp6hcDQhyHkEKT7DAmBBgBg2RQRMaklQ3SSrxuy1ge-WY0YIIQ9m5v2U0ETVzzWxLfRKlsKQN1pK+DbiISGSuSZYrqDUmpPnxSqqJdUYk7e+aMv5UdKfs7s3Qoub031XytxJGE8DzqXUWs-Ep1yyl1StKCfR6Fz7GwB9vhKFtkpWwbvz0uO1EUCs9ralZQy+Xz+ReM2O44O2m0c+fc7+WcK+UGxyqyaKO0aydsN+qktcne1sjczct8UC-8Iyfcs8wqhso8bUWBcyC+s0UKnSS8ZAUCgkG818cCp0CC+yx8n+UBl+Ly5yW+iBd8dBe+lyR+j0J+lkf2pyP8HcmBgC2BmcpBAuW2JmFBHcVBsCriO+XB+8DBQaCc3KBUjKQiOCzsbKZilUqK6yfirKWK+M6SuK0w+KuO+OhO-IQBW0P+iSf+UcuBRsi0MKUKvKuOVa5hJKbEb0GheugujhhAYBZAKCOi1EoqZoAKEq1KVU1IVio+tiT4aqQAA)

Comment: Please include the code in your question, not just a link. If it is a lot of code, reduce it down to the expected [mcve] - the minimal code required to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: What about `minimal`  reproducable example?

Comment: @kaya3, @ captain-yossarian
Added reproducable example code in the question, thanks.

Comment: There is one mistake in the above code..
I have written `isArrayOfObjects(objectKeyOrIterateeFunction)` it should have been
`isArrayOfObjects(arrayList)`. Was writing this code when I was sleeping. Sorry for this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a user defined typegurad like below:

```js
function isKeyOfAnyObject<T extends AnyObject, K extends keyof T>(objectKeyOrIterateeFunction?: K | UniqueIterateeMapFunction<T>): objectKeyOrIterateeFunction is K {
  return objectKeyOrIterateeFunction !== undefined && !isFunction(objectKeyOrIterateeFunction) ? true : false
}
```

Below is the playground link with the fix.
[Plaground link with the fix](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=9&pc=1#code/PQKhCgAIUh1ALApgO0gSUgdwE4EsAuikAhpAM6IAOx2xhkAZgK7IDG+uA9qsWefJ0w98kfEkgAjTvnycAtpE4NR4hrgA2iADSQCuvpk7YA1rmQBzRmcQA6OElQZ82AJ6jOkJhUYt2XVJwAbojY6uqcxAAmZDp6uHzI0lhGphYkfGQCQpKI4Zg2UCDA4OCgENCQAGK4AB6IkSpE8WRMRBJuUZFmlmJtuYKiLpRE5kw0DQAG8QDSiC4A8gwAgsgLEgBWiOwTBRWFxcxsHNz6swvLq-MbW-gAPAAqkIg1hMjRkCtrm+w6008vKHexjmSkg9wAfAAKTjXdhnebYNCEWiERCVXzHZAAfgAXJA-gAfSAAVWQuAAjq0kSE6IhEABZYiUdFHfwPcEASjxMO++HhiORtLRGP8+nxkAA3lBINhEPgmNgArC+XMEdSUXSWX4TgBCAC8es8b0QamQ9UgADILZAdfEtZjocr+eqhfb-BzIFjRNhWpA8QxiOoKOAAL4lQ7a1AsCmtABCLge-1e7wACng5ARcMEoTRaC4ADLxfB4+4AbQAulywRWANyQYDASCUdOZ4KKYKhcJRcARzFGmOIeOJ57JvifK6835JwF8YEuUEQyHS3PEAtFksVrTSnk3M73TgAYXk1FlsAI8Dx03AVbL5ZrDcgiWQAFpm7gMxw2yuOuE0phz4oyqQHO6S6MglBMCIQQhGEESRD2IonNGlKDgmjwjjOHyXMqULLtgeaFmQxbVuWW6QLogqom63B4qSA4uqijLMohyDsteG53g+T6vi2n5EN+WAAQQNJUSxoFmBBUEdrB3a9qKyFxmh05vGO2G8pARJpu+rbaOKGEqcBILKIu9aNu+lCaHIKD4HQopkLg5jIHQCqIHhBHriRZGAbyzqUZqLG4uKRJ0ShDF0kx1GsRC7EkZK0q4MokLxFpH5ZogkLfoR+Ach6UrkeRrDcER-YoSlOlLPhq4cZAhqljY9VmpgkAAMpyhllVrkRHJ3tK5GyvKiola0ZV8RVeY1tKYb5boiUzKqFxfDcjo+aqAoif5rLcDlkqQL1kCFcgxU7nCcz7kecgnogZ5iJe5GGsdKoLGtGrCptyATdNB3FQpiAAEpbEY0TXfAab1LgrC0pF1WGplRY2LKkRMKw6V7eRGWsKwTByEw6i0iFrT-YV2DRBxsSEHIJY3hWNXgjtqP5V9IiBIGrSLBOu5zCmvAUJEaDINScixog3RppwyNkDzNX09NwlyKWD17oex40Fd549dNn1FSIDCcCwkT439APE3iUicJoxCoIaOrEBjWM43jZIoYTgNkDYZDyCjGsa+jmPY7jhD647BNG5ElMm5wZuIBbNNxV7XuM7Hcde-LTqnUrF0q8D5bcqnLgAGos4gfNLLbfu0pEzvE15SfkSGNUkKX9sBwbleRB9NcFVr+gF+orMMPcSDsydLhcxL9RoGQACilKBuHkfR3q0tx8zveIGzuejzzfMC0LIvYGLiBjw0BqLx300K3MPdUsgJe+039St+3Hf9QqqDxFfa-94PG-c+PU8z+oJ+ccppxw5EAmWiUdZ6xbiHXKS9O6HREEyYYbwDYC33GNKqsUYaUBQZEAAcogTA6DOCYJcEuM+Dc77+0QDAom0Rq411lvAyAYCWEv0GsgwEaDyYYI6uA-KICvYcJ4I3GhdCXYCJDIw8i1M9psOmiIoaht6FkGBqDLoENCCRXbiA+Ks0yCRWWhzJ6YVXqRm2nlBmXcfqtzUeeMxEUWLQxIB1LK8N6hI09t7G21CHYDjsaTCiiAKZgipuWGOVj45dxXn3HewsLCi3FjzSo+85BmMivXC+pi-LmIdCw5hScFFxwTlA1BQcVGAznubS2NpfF23ERUuxbsPYUJrj7Bp5cJHGzCdUqOltaZRJrgneIGSWLzEgpJaeYx1B9IXiw6asTP7xL3gfI+qT5BjLejVA0Cz8rZLVLkox9Sy7NyabAgRwi5Sv30FsyMEz8BTIAZcwRS9ilewSpASEZTA4BNgYnJOCcuHlPorw0hHUXHAoIUQkhZC2kdxOffbpDC9mFJru8uOSioU8JCXw8aS8hEayxWI-xTsQ5kCkTIyAFZ5FAKUbY8lwNHFMh0ZNEofVrmcLcUWCaYZwDPEoEYEQ+AhhEBGmlKW5EiRETwBYaURJkBYwkCEeVkgI41NVRIByZh8CqrIC4OQUh1Cqr1iaaw8EpWPhxoA-lNRBXYGFaKrCi12D11brcIej0dAWxcOCCaAqhWDGGJAT1Zx64yu6BpK1hqQhRv1Yas2E0dUhADMjEkFTmXMTeuyRO7VzAAEYw5GmMIkIQvKELbOSrxNK7JIRLJLFG8VwQqxLLFE2ogVilGtoNFasIGkiTAAAHqljIBIZA5ZgA2EIERSEIrhigiWWwsMckTjxE9XWwueIWAlsEMgFthcxQPUTgnJZ9xRU4j2kSAARKa009Qr2XsgFeh6D7prXtNjU19+Vr2KpjdgL9lqr0RosABqNV6V3IFA9e+NRqoNPq1eYHVV765zsQAuwu7cu0Hv1L29QlprQbtXme4NPbn3KmQwSIkp6nWkYg1epdFbIz6Gas4botb63kFY2kIk9x92rzFMBywnbOWoFQ+h-jJ8n2CaveWiD+h8FKpCOxzd0blXYCjbxvErb4iqdjcJgaonRXid9JJq9v61MydDIxvs8RmoGqNcp1eeIYNmw03x30OmXN4f0zcsTyhu2ka85Z5dYk1250c60BtRJQ1zHc00WcRkwSJ0+UlMg67F1wMUSJ5jXHzCEdaB6Sj8nFPYHy4gQrRJbP2bNmV4pIClEBiDIgWToWyBkMTDDVYUIOM+ri2KW8iclHwsgLGdV-Tav4b2pCUb89kCQjITYeIZCOT0y9AtpbHVav0y04XKdnAWOyryx6UzKd1JkPLPR6UDG5N2hYhFxAUWqgsT6zpzJPnBracQRbZGoJWVhiBbgwEhDiFgrIfXB4WgczcqIkE2WRaBt6kGdKBOjUyHAyWID40vNyYuLqvVWGREyYhPVjKbLqOOro8x5Ece5NeX+rtYGm7ZB8HcHbZCGoW7kA7qEFWGoh6gJDKUbaMgbOagMYfEzsh69eRkA695G4kOyuPd6zt-jOmBtSgfFlgz+g4WLvw5AJZNhEAdnIfEFnyB21sIfCFytbWOrS5uLLx491lSK4448Ik27S17tVx5vgD1qaC+yxtvME2rSG92ybkIZvmes+rc28tZRCj2BQOgLAeB6CkAoCeWkPhtnqFwMCHIeQKJikMCYSNd7dhFGs-JCpwMzjDgBAZccbu9It6BIlxcblVxZVJtuXOZ1lannPJeGKGvkc2POao9RCNwaQ2cdg1x7kiIeMRsjYbHTTm0Jny7WHOPenYKR9ExBkfV6O+Hpvce-Nya70SfvZJ9QNzTAiafOOstTsmOHxnUfYgSeaxn4-LIpzK1LWwkqEDIquzuxWTDbTTb73y-Jkr0JFofr9KRIsIJxDJJxf7Dw-6XRZw5wrT5yFzFwQEPwhxUrTR1wwzkFIHBz0IvIILFTvyFyLADxrw-xHwTzTKzxqqzaSpnxLKX6PTX68y34hL37mBJKHySwnx7LZIfxkF+IByPzsIh5kAfzsHfzEFiE8HPIEr0wYrkQpbAF77EyZYlJdzYoZqg4QrL5QrA6wqbYsKIqNJ-KqJUH5RopezGH5RYpU44pyB4qrhSL0zEoqG74eGSJ7TSJ7Q0rkTFL0rmFAzngaIL7aIsS8pAA)

Please let me know, if you think of a better solution.